# FFmpeg multicast packet filtering with UDP

Tags: ffmpeg, udp, rtsp, multicast, rtp

**Problem Scenario:**
I am trying to capture *multiple* multicast cameras on a network with FFmpeg. Upon receiving the streams, I find that each FFmpeg instance running is receiving and decoding the packets destined for the other instances. This causes the video of each instance to flicker between the correct image and the images of all the other cameras. Each camera uses the same destination UDP port and I believe this is the reason its happening.

**Example**
Process 1

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport udp_multicast -i "rtsp://192.168.1.1/stream1m" test1.mp4
```

Process 2

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport udp_multicast -i "rtsp://192.168.1.2/stream1m" test2.mp4
```

**Expected Output**
Each MP4 contains only one, non-interrupted stream

**Actual Output**
As described above

I've trawled through FFmpeg's docs, as well as extensive 'googling' however I can only see a way to filter incoming packets when using an rtp:// or udp:// input. This isn't possible in this application as I want to use RTSP for the SDP it provides.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Badly I have same issue with this behaviour. Have you found any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work using different multicast IPs and ports. The trick is the ports - they have to be different on the stream side, even if the IPs are different.

This seems to be a problem with ffmpeg.